# Why does this method reference assignment compile?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm struggling to see why the following code compiles:

```
public class MethodRefs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<MethodRefs, String> f;

        f = MethodRefs::getValueStatic;

        f = MethodRefs::getValue;
    }

    public static String getValueStatic(MethodRefs smt) {
        return smt.getValue();
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return "4";
    }

}
```

I can see why the first assignment is valid - `getValueStatic` obviously matches the specified `Function` type (it accepts a `MethodRefs` object and returns a `String`), but the second one baffles me - the `getValue` method accepts no arguments, so why is it still valid to assign it to `f`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lambda with non-static methods in Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784337/lambda-with-non-static-methods-in-java-8)

Comment: Also [:: (double colon) operator in Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8/22245383#22245383) and [Use of double colons - difference between static and non-static method references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982972/use-of-double-colons-difference-between-static-and-non-static-method-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The second one

```
f = MethodRefs::getValue;
```

is the same as

```
f = (MethodRefs m) -> m.getValue();
```

For non-static methods there is always an implicit argument which is represented as `this` in the callee.

NOTE: The implementation is slightly different at the byte code level but it does the same thing.

Comment: Note that the implicit argument can be made explicit (as of Java 8): `public String getValue(MethodRefs this)` is legal and identical to `public String getValue()`.

Comment: @Pokechu22 I didn't know that. Is there a name for that construct?

Comment: @immibis: [the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1) (§8.4.1) calls it a "receiver parameter" as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 9):

A non-static method essentially takes its `this` reference as a special kind of argument.  Normally that argument is written in a special way (before the method name, instead of within the parentheses after it), but the concept is the same.  The `getValue` method takes a `MethodRefs` object (its `this`) and returns a string, so it's compatible with the `Function<MethodRefs, String>` interface.

Answer (score 9):

Lets flesh it out a bit:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class MethodRefs {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<MethodRefs, String> f;


    final MethodRefs ref = new MethodRefs();

    f = MethodRefs::getValueStatic;
    f.apply(ref);
    //is equivalent to 
    MethodRefs.getValueStatic(ref);

    f = MethodRefs::getValue;
    f.apply(ref);
    //is now equivalent to 
    ref.getValue();
  }

  public static String getValueStatic(MethodRefs smt) {
    return smt.getValue();
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return "4";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In the Java Tutorial it is explained that there are 4 different types of method references:

1. reference to a static method
2. reference to an instance method of a particular object
3. [reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#type)
4. reference to a constructor

Your case is #3, meaning that when you have an instance of `MethodRef` i.e. `ref`, calling `apply` on your function `f` will be equivalent to `String s = ref.getValue()`.

Answer (score 5):

For non-static methods, the type of `this` is considered implicitly to be the first argument type. Since it's of type `MethodRefs`, the types check out.